# Using optionRenderer with Select.Aysnc (react-select)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I can't find in the documentations how to use `optionRenderer` prop with react-select async (Select.Async)

[here is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50324434/react-select-how-can-i-use-the-optionrenderer-prop-with-the-async-component) that already been answered, but the `renderOptions` is not being called at all

here is my a snippet of my code:

```
renderOption = (option) => {
    return (
        <div>
            // for example:
            {option.label}: {option.value}
        </div>
    )
}


<Select.Async
    placeholder={placeholder}
    loadOptions={(inputValue) => this.asyncLoadOptions(inputValue)}
    isClearable
    onChange={(value, e) => {
      this.onDropDownFilterChange(value, e)
    }}
    onMenuScrollToBottom={this.fetchDropDownNextPage}
    defaultOptions={defaultOptions}
    defaultValue={defaultValue}
    styles={this.props.hasError ? customStyles : undefined}
    optionRenderer={this.renderOption}

/>
```

Here I want to keep the functioality and styles for each dropDown item as is (e.g onMouseOver and so on) I just want to format how the items are shown in the list, so is this the right way to do it? or there no other option than using the `components` prop.

I was able to achieve the formatting right using the `components` prop, but I lost the styles, and all the mouse events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so for those who are looking for the answer, this is what I ended up using and it does the job: (unrelated code has been removed to keep the snippet concise)

```
import AsyncSelect  from 'react-select/async';
import { components } from 'react-select';

const Option = props => {
    return (
        <components.Option {...props} >
            {props.data.label}<br/>
            <small style={{color: 'gray'}}>
                {props.data.manufacturerName || 'Unknown'} | {props.data.assetGroupDescription || 'Unknown'}
            </small>
        </components.Option>
    )};

class FilterDropDownMenu extends Component {

render() {
    return (
        <>
            <label htmlFor={id}>{translate(placeholder)}</label>
            <AsyncSelect
                {...this.props}
                isClearable
                onChange={(value, e) => {
                    this.onDropDownFilterChange(value, e)
                }}
                onMenuScrollToBottom={this.fetchDropDownNextPage}
                defaultOptions={defaultOptions}
                defaultValue={defaultValue}
                styles={hasError ? customStyles : undefined}
                components={{ Option }}
            />
        </>
    )
   }
}
```

This way, I get the formatting that I want, And I don't loose the built in functionality of react-select (mouse events and styling and so on).